# fable from distribution to confidence interval

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I manage to use fable for the forecast then get the result
[image]

could I have some guidance on how to change this distribution to 80% 95% confidence interval? thank you!

you can use the sample code here to get the distribution

```
result <–USAccDeaths %>% as_tsibble %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(log(value) ~ pdq(0,1,1) + PDQ(0,1,1)))%>%
  forecast(h=12)
```

Answer (score 9):

The `hilo()` function allows you to extract confidence intervals from a forecast distribution. It can be used on either the distribution vector, or the fable itself.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fable)
result <- as_tsibble(USAccDeaths) %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(log(value) ~ pdq(0,1,1) + PDQ(0,1,1)))%>%
  forecast(h=12)

result %>% 
  mutate(`80%` = hilo(value, 80))
#> # A fable: 12 x 5 [1M]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model    index             value  .mean                    `80%`
#>    <chr>     <mth>            <dist>  <dbl>                   <hilo>
#>  1 arima  1979 Jan   t(N(9, 0.0014))  8290. [ 7899.082,  8689.169]80
#>  2 arima  1979 Feb t(N(8.9, 0.0018))  7453. [ 7055.860,  7859.100]80
#>  3 arima  1979 Mar   t(N(9, 0.0022))  8276. [ 7789.719,  8774.054]80
#>  4 arima  1979 Apr t(N(9.1, 0.0025))  8584. [ 8036.304,  9144.752]80
#>  5 arima  1979 May t(N(9.2, 0.0029))  9499. [ 8849.860, 10166.302]80
#>  6 arima  1979 Jun t(N(9.2, 0.0033))  9900. [ 9180.375, 10639.833]80
#>  7 arima  1979 Jul t(N(9.3, 0.0037)) 10988. [10145.473, 11857.038]80
#>  8 arima  1979 Aug t(N(9.2, 0.0041)) 10132. [ 9315.840, 10974.140]80
#>  9 arima  1979 Sep t(N(9.1, 0.0045))  9138. [ 8368.585,  9933.124]80
#> 10 arima  1979 Oct t(N(9.1, 0.0049))  9391. [ 8567.874, 10243.615]80
#> 11 arima  1979 Nov t(N(9.1, 0.0052))  8863. [ 8056.754,  9699.824]80
#> 12 arima  1979 Dec t(N(9.1, 0.0056))  9356. [ 8474.732, 10271.739]80

result %>% 
  hilo(level = c(80, 95))
#> # A tsibble: 12 x 6 [1M]
#> # Key:       .model [1]
#>    .model    index             value  .mean                    `80%`
#>    <chr>     <mth>            <dist>  <dbl>                   <hilo>
#>  1 arima  1979 Jan   t(N(9, 0.0014))  8290. [ 7899.082,  8689.169]80
#>  2 arima  1979 Feb t(N(8.9, 0.0018))  7453. [ 7055.860,  7859.100]80
#>  3 arima  1979 Mar   t(N(9, 0.0022))  8276. [ 7789.719,  8774.054]80
#>  4 arima  1979 Apr t(N(9.1, 0.0025))  8584. [ 8036.304,  9144.752]80
#>  5 arima  1979 May t(N(9.2, 0.0029))  9499. [ 8849.860, 10166.302]80
#>  6 arima  1979 Jun t(N(9.2, 0.0033))  9900. [ 9180.375, 10639.833]80
#>  7 arima  1979 Jul t(N(9.3, 0.0037)) 10988. [10145.473, 11857.038]80
#>  8 arima  1979 Aug t(N(9.2, 0.0041)) 10132. [ 9315.840, 10974.140]80
#>  9 arima  1979 Sep t(N(9.1, 0.0045))  9138. [ 8368.585,  9933.124]80
#> 10 arima  1979 Oct t(N(9.1, 0.0049))  9391. [ 8567.874, 10243.615]80
#> 11 arima  1979 Nov t(N(9.1, 0.0052))  8863. [ 8056.754,  9699.824]80
#> 12 arima  1979 Dec t(N(9.1, 0.0056))  9356. [ 8474.732, 10271.739]80
#> # … with 1 more variable: `95%` <hilo>
```

To extract the numerical values from a `<hilo>` object, you can use the `unpack_hilo()` function, or obtain each part using `<hilo>$lower`, `<hilo>$upper` and `<hilo>$level`.

```r
result %>% 
  hilo(level = c(80, 95)) %>% 
  unpack_hilo("80%")
#> # A tsibble: 12 x 7 [1M]
#> # Key:       .model [1]
#>    .model    index             value  .mean `80%_lower` `80%_upper`
#>    <chr>     <mth>            <dist>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 arima  1979 Jan   t(N(9, 0.0014))  8290.       7899.       8689.
#>  2 arima  1979 Feb t(N(8.9, 0.0018))  7453.       7056.       7859.
#>  3 arima  1979 Mar   t(N(9, 0.0022))  8276.       7790.       8774.
#>  4 arima  1979 Apr t(N(9.1, 0.0025))  8584.       8036.       9145.
#>  5 arima  1979 May t(N(9.2, 0.0029))  9499.       8850.      10166.
#>  6 arima  1979 Jun t(N(9.2, 0.0033))  9900.       9180.      10640.
#>  7 arima  1979 Jul t(N(9.3, 0.0037)) 10988.      10145.      11857.
#>  8 arima  1979 Aug t(N(9.2, 0.0041)) 10132.       9316.      10974.
#>  9 arima  1979 Sep t(N(9.1, 0.0045))  9138.       8369.       9933.
#> 10 arima  1979 Oct t(N(9.1, 0.0049))  9391.       8568.      10244.
#> 11 arima  1979 Nov t(N(9.1, 0.0052))  8863.       8057.       9700.
#> 12 arima  1979 Dec t(N(9.1, 0.0056))  9356.       8475.      10272.
#> # … with 1 more variable: `95%` <hilo>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Mitchell, thank you for the input. was trying the second way. but still. how could i get the two numbers 7899.082 and 8689.169 in numeric out of the <hilo> frame? I need to use that two number to draw line or push the result into database in 2 columns. Thank you!

Comment: was able to use summary(level=80) to get the <hilo> object. but not able to get the number in dataframe format. create a function. (unpack_hilo <- function(hilo_col) {
  hilo_col %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    t() %>% 
    matrix(nrow = 3) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rename(lwr = V1, upr = V2, level = V3)
}  ; use t_p <- cle_pre %>% 
   summary(level=85) %>%
   as_tibble() %>%  
   select('85%') %>% 
   unpack_hilo()  )able to get the information out but they are in 'list' format unable to change them to data frame,  not able to save it that in csv

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you!  I was previously using a mutate(lower_95 = map_dbl(`95%`, ~.[[1]]), upper_95 = map_dbl(`95%`,~.[[2]]) to get the lower bound and upper bound, and with a recent package update this code no longer works. (perhaps it was never meant to)

Comment: Obtaining upper and lower values is even easier now, you can use `$` to extract `lower`, `upper`, and `level` (with code-completion hints). For example, `fbl$hilo$upper` will get the `upper` bound from the `hilo` column of `fbl`.